# Default Activity not Found, Error Running App

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is my AndroidManifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.mypos">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".PrintManager"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_print" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MCRManager"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_msr" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ICCManager"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_icc" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

It was working just fine, until today, i'm not sure what to do.
I've already tried Invalidate Caches and Restart, Cleaning Project, and Rebuiliding 
Edit: I added some of the code that got lost in the copy-page

Comment: Your Manifest file has no problem in it. Everything in your MainActivity.java is okay??

Comment: Well it's not showing any errors, the error is coming and going, some times i can run it but then i add codelines and when i build it everything comes down

Comment: Okay now try to build an apk by build>Build Apk. And tell me what's happening.

Comment: BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
28 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 23 up-to-date

Comment: That was the result

Comment: Okay now take the apk on your phone and try to install and run it. let me know what's going on.

Comment: The Apk crashes

Comment: then I have just one suggestion for you, open a new project and copy your files there .

Comment: Can't help you much though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your manifest tag? 
Also add category to other activities.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.user.mypos">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".PrintManager"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_print">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MCRManager"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_msr">

        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ICCManager"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_icc">

        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You are missing this part <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="your_package_name">

Comment: Woops yeah sorry, it is there, it was an issue with the copy-paste

Comment: Thanks, though, I'm still trying

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.user.mypos"> i added it and i'm still having the same "Error running 'app': Default Activity Not Found"

Comment: Everything else seems okay. Try copying your entire project in another folder rename it and then open it from android studio

Comment: did you add this for all other activites? android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

Comment: No! sorry, should i put it inside the <activity>?